# Using Nokogiri to create XML element with namespace

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I use Nokogiri that would create XML. I want to have the following structure:

```
<content:encode>text</content>
```

I have tried this code:

```
xml.content['encoded'] {xml.text "text"}
```

but it gives me an error.

How do I write this correctly? A similar example is in *[Referencing declared namespaces](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html)*.

Comment: Good job telling us what code you tried. In the future, you should always supply the exact error message you received, not just that you got an error.

Answer (score 11):

1. Your example doesn't make sense; you say that you want "encode" and then you attempt to write "encoded".
2. Your example doesn't make sense, as it is not valid XML. You have an opening `encode` tag with the namespace `content`, and then you try to close it with a `content` tag. You want either `<content:encode>text</content:encode>` or you want `<encode:content>text</encode:content>`. *(Which do you want?)*
3. You did not follow the example in the link you gave. If you want a `content` element with namespace `encoded`, then per the example you should write:

   ```
   xml['encoded'].content{ xml.text "text" }
   ```
4. However, also per the example, you must declare any namespaces you want to reference. So do this:

   ```
   require 'nokogiri'

   builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
     xml.root('xmlns:encoded' => 'bar') do
       xml['encoded'].content{ xml.text "text" }
     end
   end
   puts builder.to_xml
   #=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
   #=> <root xmlns:encoded="bar">
   #=>   <encoded:content>text</encoded:content>
   #=> </root>
   ```

**Edit**: If you really only need a single element with no root, using Nokogiri is overkill. Just do:

```
str = "Hello World"
xml = "<encoded:content>#{str}</encoded:content>"
puts xml
#=> <encoded:content>Hello World</encoded:content>
```

If you really need to use Nokogiri, but only want the first sub-root element, do:

```
xml_str = builder.doc.root.children.first.to_s
#=> "<encoded:content>text</encoded:content>"
```

Comment: Thank you. But we need to get just such a structure.
<encoded:content>text</encoded:content> 
<root xmlns:encoded="bar"> .... </root> - extra lines, they are not needed

Comment: @Delaf I do not understand your comments. Did what I write not help you? Are you saying that you want/need no newlines in your Nokogiri XML output?

Comment: Your example-works. But it adds extra lines to the code http://pastie.org/1581058

Comment: @Delaf I've edited the answer to possibly address your needs.

Comment: You have no idea how much you helped me. Thanks.